# Flutter Plugin: crash_dump.cpp: failed to attach to thread 185: Permission denied

Tags: android, multithreading, flutter

I am developing a Flutter Plugin and a simple piano keyboard layout which calls the Flutter plugin when `onKeyPressed` and `onKeyUp` the piano keys. The piano app can run in an emulator, and can produce the sound. However, from time to time, the app would crash with the error message:

```
F/crash_dump32(22593): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 185: Permission denied
```

and in the emulator, a pop-up warning shows `System UI isn't responding` with options: `Close the app` or `Wait`.

If I chose `Wait`, it will resume to work, until the same thread error repeats itself.

In my implementation, I have a class written in Kotlin that will be run in a thread:

```
class Synth : Runnable {
    private lateinit var mThread: Thread
    private var mRunning = false
    private var mFreq = 440.0
    private var mAmp = 0.0
    private var mNumKeysDown = 0


    fun start() {
        mThread = Thread(this)
        mRunning = true
        mThread.start()
    }

    fun stop() {
        mRunning = false
    }

    fun keyDown(key: Int): Int {
        mFreq = Math.pow(1.0594630f.toDouble(), key.toDouble() - 69.0) * 440.0
        mAmp = 1.0
        mNumKeysDown += 1
        return mNumKeysDown
    }
}
```

and the following pieces are how the `Synth` class is called from the Plugin written in Kotlin:

1. When the Plugin is initiated from a Flutter client:

```
class PianoPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {

fun setup(plugin: PianoPlugin, binaryMessenger: BinaryMessenger) {
      plugin.channel = MethodChannel(channelName)
      plugin.channel.setMethodCallHandler(plugin)
      plugin.synth = Synth()
      plugin.synth.start()              // <- Start the thread
    }
```

```
  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      result.success(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE)
    } else if (call.method == "onKeyDown"){
      try {
        val arguments: ArrayList<Int> = call.arguments as ArrayList<Int>
        val numKeysDown: Int = synth.keyDown(arguments.get(0) as Int)    // <- Function call

        result.success(numKeysDown)
      } catch (ex: Exception) {
        result.error("100", ex.message, ex.getStackTrace())
      }
}
```

I wonder if anyone has bumped into similar thread issue can share some insights of the possible causes. Very appreciated!

Comment: Same problem with fresh Flutter project, i think the problem from android version 11 of emulator... try to change AVD to new one with api 28 will solve the problem...

Comment: Yes I was using android API 30 version for the emulator. Thanks for confirming the issue!

Comment: Same problem here did you find a solution?

Comment: @AnasSafi was pointing the right direction in my case. I downgrade the API to 28 and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

i solved it by cold booting the emulator.

Comment: What is cold booting? how can I cold boot my emulator?

Comment: just google it.

Comment: Well doing too many times will give the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Updating the android version to 12 when creating a new Device(using the virtual device manager) solved my problem.

You can update your android version by following these steps:

1. Choose 'Virtual Device Manager

[image: Choose 'Virtual Device Manager']

2. Click on 'Create Device' on the top

[image: Click on 'Create Device' on the top]

3. Choose your hardware

[image: Choose your hardware]

4. Select Android version above 11.0 and finish the process

[image: Select version above 11.0]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because graphics card or driver I tried this command when launching the emulator:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_3_API_30 -gpu mode -gpu swiftshader_indirect
```

in android studio.

if this command doesn't work try adding an emulator path to the System environment